# how to get the line style in visio workflow diagram using c#?

Tags: c#-4.0, automation, visio

```
var line = shape.Cells["ConLineRouteExt"].FormulaU; //0：Default，1:Straight，2：Curved
```

I can get the line route ,but how can I get the line style property ?

ex: Straight or Right angle, because as the default I can't distinguish between them

thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'm setting it:

```
connector.CellsU["ShapeRouteStyle"].ResultIUForce = (double)Visio.VisCellVals.visLORouteCenterToCenter;  // or .visLORouteRightAngle
```

I guess you could read it this way:

```
var lineStyle = shape.CellsU["ShapeRouteStyle"].FormulaU;
```

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/HV080950301.aspx.